# Python asyncio NotImplementedError

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Im trying to run something basic for testing purposes and cant thru this issue. Not alot of wisdom here any ideas?

```
import sys
import asyncio
import signal

def ctrl_c():
    print("hit!")
    sys.exit(1)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, ctrl_c)
loop.run_forever()
```

Im running this in IDLE python 3.6, and the traceback is:

```
Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
============== RESTART: C:\Users\benb\Desktop\reasyncio\loop.py ==============
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\benb\Desktop\reasyncio\loop.py", line 10, in <module>
    loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, ctrl_c)
  File "C:\Users\benb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 499, in add_signal_handler
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
>>>
```

Any tips help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tries to tell you that support for signals is not available on Windows. This is because Windows itself doesn't support signals as means of inter-process communication. What Windows calls signals can only trap certain low-level conditions that arise within the process, such as floating-point errors or user pressing <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>. See e.g. [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shrib/2008/05/23/signals-on-windows/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

This has a GitHub issue page https://github.com/saghul/aiodns/issues/86

It suggests that you add the following to your code:

```
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
```

Hope this helps someone.